# Fetch YouTube comments in JSON format

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I want to fetch youtube comments on a particular video using googleapis. In this LINK [How to fetch comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments) they have mentioned two types of feeds which are relevance and chronological order based, but I want to use googleapis and I want the response in JSON. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please give the following link a shot - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO-ID/comments?v=2&alt=json

The "v=2" ensures you're using youtube API v2 and the "alt=json" is requesting json rather than xml.

Simply swap "VIDEO-ID" with whatever video you are interested in gaining the comments from.

Comment: [“This site can’t be reached”](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/stuTk2vTobc/comments?v=2&alt=json) (gdata.youtube.com)